# Clojure dynamic keyword builder function returns unexpected results

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure, cursive

When I define my function in the repl, it works as I expect. When I drop it into a namespace (i.e. my app) and reload the repl, I lose the `namespace` component on the keyword. I am not sure what I am missing here.

```
;; Repl
(defn repl-keyword-gen [k str] (keyword (name k) str))

(repl-keyword-gen :test "example")
;;=> :test/example


;; App - example.core
(defn app-no-sym-keyword-gen [str] (keyword "test" str))
(defn app-with-sym-keyword-gen [k str] (keyword (name k) str))

(app-no-sym-keyword-gen "example")
;;=> :test/example

(app-with-sym-keyword-gen :test "example")
;;=> :example   <----- Not sure about this one right here
```

Would appreciate insight/explanation into why this keyword builder returns different results.

REPL
[image: Repl_screenshot]

APP
[image: App_screenshot]

*Edited* - screenshots

Comment: Restart your REPL and paste your code from the question to see that it works correctly. You might have not defined your `app-with-sym-keyword-gen` correctly (or overwrote it with a different version in the REPL).

Comment: Cannot reproduce `user=> (ns example.core)
nil
example.core=> (defn app-no-sym-keyword-gen [str] (keyword "test" str))
#'example.core/app-no-sym-keyword-gen
example.core=> (defn app-with-sym-keyword-gen [k str] (keyword (name k) str))
#'example.core/app-with-sym-keyword-gen
example.core=> (app-no-sym-keyword-gen "example")
:test/example
example.core=> (app-with-sym-keyword-gen :test "example")
:test/example`

Comment: I am connecting to the NREPL server in Intellij Cursive once the server is started. Restarted everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there may be a problem in your environment.

I tested using plain-old `lein run` and got the namespaced keyword:

```
(ns clj.core
  (:require 
    [tupelo.core :as t]
    [clj-time.core :as tm] 
  ))
(t/refer-tupelo)

;; App - example.core
(defn app-no-sym-keyword-gen    [str]   (keyword "test"   str))
(defn app-with-sym-keyword-gen  [k str] (keyword (name k) str))

(spyx (app-no-sym-keyword-gen "example"))

(spyx (app-with-sym-keyword-gen :test "example"))

(defn -main [& args]
  (println "-main"))
```

Results:

```
~/clj > lein run    
(app-no-sym-keyword-gen "example") => :test/example
(app-with-sym-keyword-gen :test "example") => :test/example
-main
```

To get the `(spyx ...)` part to work, you need this in your project.clj:

```
:dependencies [
  [tupelo "0.9.9"] 
  ...
```

Comment: Not sure how to fix it, but appreciate the answer. Thanks for taking the time.